# margin 0 auto centers an element, why doesn't margin 1 auto do the same?

Tags: css

I understand that `margin: 0 auto;` means a margin of size 0 on the top and bottom of the element, and a margin of size whatever is available, divided equally, on the left and right of the element.

This works as I would expect in the following example - but when I change it to `margin: 1 auto` (or any other number) the inner element moves all they way over to the left. I would have expected it to remain centered but to have shrunk vertically.

Code:

```css
#outer {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
#inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your code fails when you change it to `margin: 1 auto` is that `1` is not a valid CSS measurement.

Only `0` can be written without a unit (such as `px` or `pt`). If you change it to `margin: 1px auto`, it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you! So is `0` special in that it doesn't need a unit?

Comment: Yep! This is a gotcha that has tripped me up many times. (The reasoning is that while 1pt is different from 1px or 1em, 0 is a length of 0 in any unit.)

Comment: Definitely makes sense! I guess now is a good time to figure out when to us px pt em etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pixels after auto.

```css
#inner {
 
    margin:auto 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background:red;
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: `margin:5px auto ;` This solution Dosn't work perfectlly so the correct solution is here `margin:auto 5px;`